# making a data application that will store data on each day on the calendar

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

i am having a bit of a problem, i am sure this question has been asked but i cant figure my way to google it or find it here.

i am building an web app with angular and node.

my task is that every day (date) will have its own data and users will be able to change the data in the next 3 days. admin offcurse will be able to do whatever he wants.

my real question is: how am i going to save the calander in my DB. eventually this web app will be used for years so how am i going to insert all the dates to my DB. how can i handle this situation in the client side. i want the admin to be able to choose let say a date that is 4 months from today and be able to change their things. what should i do here, and how am i going to insert all the dates inside the DB.

thanks.

Comment: Do you have predetermined data that you want stored initially and then they can choose to change it at a later stage?

Comment: there will be some predefined data. but most of the future data will be changed and added by the admin and thus by the users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of database should be your first question: SQL, noSQL, Custom, other?

Next, decide how your client and server will communicate: Ajax, Websocket, REST ect..

Then establish authentication.

Then work out a way for the client to alter the database, but establish rules, or design it in a limited way.

Then worry about calculating dates and such...

You can go for a low storage cost method by only generating a record when a date is altered away from default.  This way you will likely need to seek the database until you find the record(by matching a date field).  This can be made faster by breaking the database into multiple databases for certain time ranges.

Or you can go for the faster, but more storage intensive method of creating each record from past to future that will be accessed.  This method you can calculate the right record index by using the date.

There are other ways as well, but these might be the most simple to implement.

Also I think this might be useful for calculating date names and such: https://code.google.com/p/datejs/

Good Luck